# Converting 3d polygon feature class into MultiPatch feature class using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: polygon, arcgis-10.3, convert, 3d, multipatch

I've got a polygon feature class with z values enabled. The polygon entities represent billboards. I'm looking for a way to convert those polygons into MultiPatch feature class entities. I'm using ArcGIS Desktop, version 10.3.

I've tried to use '[Layer 3D To Feature Class](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/layer-3d-to-feature-class.htm)' Geoprocessing tool. I've inserted the required parameters which are the 3d layer (**not feature class!)** as input, an output multipatch feature class and a grouping definition by the OBJECTID field. It didn't work: my output had the same amount of entities only they all were having the same geometry.

How do I to convert polygon entities with z values (3d) into multipatch feature class?

Comment: please [edit] your Question to include an outline of how you tried to "use 'Layer 3D To Feature Class' Geoprocessing tool"

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons why 'Layer 3D To Feature Class'will fail. Without more information, we cannot be sure why it failed in this case.

One clue is that you are converting billboards. The most recent ArcGIS Pro docs say:

> The Layer 3D To Feature Class docs for ArcGIS Pro state "[Marker
>   symbols that are billboarded. The position of these 2D symbols are
>   dynamically oriented to face the camera position in a 3D scene, so
>   they have no fixed orientation that can be used for exporting.

It lists several other caveats why the conversion might not work.

You report that your "output had the same amount of entities only they all were having the same geometry."
You can check whether the geometry is MULTIPATCH or POLYGON on the Feature Layer Properties -> Source -> Geometry.

If grouping by ObjectID then you will have the same number of entities - i.e one multipatch for each polygon. In this case, what is the advantage of the conversion?
It makes sense to use this function to group a collection of 3D polygon faces into a single multipatch [polyhedron](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polyhedron.html).